# Align 3 elements inside a list-group-item in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a radio button, an input and some text inside one of my list-group-items, it looks good @desktop but @mobile it goes one on top of the other.

This is my code so far

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <span style="color: #990000; font-size:17px;"><strong>8,55 €</strong></span> text
         <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><input name="1" type="radio"> 1 text <strong>8,55 €</strong></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input name="2" type="radio"> 3 text <strong>8,55 €</strong></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input name="3" type="radio"> 6 text <strong>8,55 €</strong></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"><input name="n" type="radio" ></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name ="text" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="12"></div><div class="col-md-8" >text<strong>8,55 €</strong></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there anything I can do to have it responsive and aligned in mobile as well as dekstop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `col-xs-*` in place of `col-md-*`: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4311/)

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <input name="n" type="radio" >
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" name ="text" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="12">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8" >
    text<strong>8,55 €</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gatza: I don't think you can get around that -- it's due to the padding on each column. If you remove the padding (or reduce it) on one or all of the columns it'll align like you want but it's not good practice (because you're modifying the grid).

Comment: Thanks jason, i've managed to get them looking good now adding additional classes in my columns!